# Theory / Rationale Behind ActiveRecord::Base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, theory, rails-activerecord, framework-design

beginner at Rails here.

Can you please help me wrap my head around the theory behind the very, tippy, top portion of most code samples that I see? 'The ActiveRecord::Base', 'Application Controller', & 'ActionController::Base' portions?

1. What would you call these three? Are they all objects? Classes?
2. I understand 'class X < ActiveRecord::Base' is to create an object in the Model, & that 'class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base' to create an object in the Controller... so is there something similar for creating an object in the View, just to round it off on all three components of MVC?

Answer (score 1):

`ActiveRecord::Base`, `ApplicationController` and `ActionController::Base` are all classes. You would need to create an instance one of those to get an object, but you'll never do that. Instead you'll extend them to create new subclasses then create instances of those.

I believe there is a base class for views, but you should never see it under normal usage. Typically you'll be creating view **templates** rather than view **classes**, so you won't be dealing with Ruby classes in that section of the framework.

Answer (score 1):

To add to what's already been said, as it's all accurate.

> I understand 'class X < ActiveRecord::Base' is to create an object in the Model, & that 'class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base' to create an object in the Controller... so is there something similar for creating an object in the View, just to round it off on all three components of MVC?

This is down the right path, but there are some semantic differences.

`class User < ActiveRecord::Base` merely creates a subclass of ActiveRecord::Base. Until you do something like `User.create()` do you get an instance of that class, which may sometimes be referred to as an object.

A subclass is a special word for a class that has a parent.  In ruby, you may remember classes are, quite confusingly, all subclasses of the Object class.

Also, subclassing ActiveRecord::Base shouldn't be thought of as creating an object in the Model.  Instead, consider your subclass as a description of a model (which is generally some data that you wish to store).  **Every subclass is a model itself.** It's all semantics, but it may help your understanding.

The same goes with the controller.  You're not creating an object in the controller, instead you're creating a brand new description of a controller.  That description isn't really concrete until it gets instantiated, which with rails happens automagically when you or a user request a page from the application.

Finally, there is indeed a class to round out the trio called ActionView::Base.  Rails creates it automatically with a call to `render` in your controller.

Comment: Semantics definitely help reinforce the concepts I've been trying to learn. And you don't know nothin' 'til you can explain it to your grandmother...

So:'class User < ActiveRecord::Base' & 'User.create()'...(1) 'User' is a subclass of the 'ActiveRecord::Base' class & a description of the model (2) 'User.create()' creates an instance of subclass user

Comment: Exactly, and the point of all this subclassing is it gives you certain functionality and tools.  Subclassing ActiveRecord::Base gives you all of the functions you use on your model.  Things like finders (`User.find(id)`, `User.where(condition: 'value')`) validations (`validates_presence_of :cheese`), etc. all come from that inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord::Base ,ActionController::Base ,are the MVC based classes.  However, you can create model or controller without extending those classes, then they will not having the features that provided by the classes.

however,in the view, commonly, there is no one to create object or model in the view. This can ensure to increase the readability and maintainability of your code. It will show more clean code. Besides, in the particular View like index.rb , it is actually connected with the controller,which you able to get the object instance that you initialize in the controller and use it to display your data in the view.